# What is the problem with the StrComp code below

Tags: vba, ms-access

The code below seems to have an issue that I can't see, can someone please advise me what I've done wrong?

```
If StrComp(Nz(TempVars!UserName), "Developer", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 And StrComp(Nz(TempVars!Password), "-Hget%$12l", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
```

Comment: Did you mean to use an `Or`?

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you actually seeing happen?

Comment: i am expecting the code to check the text box username is Developer and the text box password is -Hget%$12l and then let it pass, otherwise it goes to another if statement that works, where it looks up a table, but all I get is the error code, So I need it to check the condition of the 2 items. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: What error code? If the strings match, function returns 0. Works for me.

Comment: To elaborate on what June7 said: the comparison code is correct so the problem should be in the calls to TempVars.  What is TempVars?

Comment: These are the tempvars, I'm sorry but I am not a professional programmer, I just want to learn about programming and I am stumbling my way through.
TempVars.Add "UserName", "Developer"
        TempVars.Add "Password", "-Hget%$12l"
        TempVars.Add "Admin", "-1"

Comment: I figured it out, This is the code that worked.

If StrComp(Nz(Me.txtUserName), "Developer", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 And StrComp(Nz(Me.txtPassword), "Try1", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the issue, the corrected code is.  Thanks everyone, Appreciated.

If StrComp(Nz(Me.txtUserName), "Developer", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 And StrComp(Nz(Me.txtPassword), "Try1", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then